# How to check if the string is reshaped in APL?

Tags: reshape, apl, dyalog

How to check if the string is reshaped? Example: "aab" returns 0 because "a" can't be reshaped to this string nor any other shorter string.

Another example is "aabbaab" returns 1 because "aabb" can be reshaped to this string.

A lot of examples can found this:

### Returns 1

```
101
abba
abcab
abacedabarab
abcdefedabc
!@#~€!
```

### Returns 0

```
aA
~
[][][][]][-
abcac
aecec
```

Is there a lambda function that does this task?

NOTE: if you are not familiar with APL then read [this](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Reshape)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The task essentially boils down to checking if we can cycle a certain substring of a given string, so that we get the aforementioned string back. A straightforward solution follows:

```
{(⊂⍵)∊(≢⍵)⍴¨¯1↓,\⍵}
```

or, tacit:

```
(⊂∊≢⍴¨¯1↓,\)
```

Let's unpack the dfn:

```
{(⊂⍵)∊(≢⍵)⍴¨¯1↓,\⍵}
               ,\⍵       prefixes of the input
            ¯1↓          ignore the last one
      (≢⍵)⍴¨             reshape each of the prefixes so
                         that it has the same length as input

 (⊂⍵)∊                   check if input appears anywhere in the list.
```

*Prefixes* is the following operation:

```
      ,\ 'Hello!'
┌─┬──┬───┬────┬─────┬──────┐
│H│He│Hel│Hell│Hello│Hello!│
└─┴──┴───┴────┴─────┴──────┘
```